# How to iterate uneven arrays?

Tags: ruby

here i have two uneven arrays(size of array is not equal),  i have to append insert when the arr1  numbers matches in arr2.but when condition become false the zero should only add one time instead of repeating. below is the code

```
arr2 =[     [[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 5],
            [[31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 14],
            [[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1], 22],
            [[28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3], 31], 
            [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], 35],
            [[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 44],
            [[29, 30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0], 53] 
            ] 
arr1 = [5, 0, 14, 0, 22, 0, 31, 35, 0, 44, 0, 53] 

cc = []
arr1.each do|item_arr1|
    arr2.each_with_index do|item_arr2,index|
        if item_arr1 == arr2[index][-1] 
            cc << item_arr2
        else 
            cc << 0
        end 
    end 
end
```

output:

```
[
  [ [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 5 ], 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 

  [ [31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 14 ], 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 

  [ [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1], 22 ], 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 

  [ [28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3], 31 ], 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 

  [ [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], 35 ], 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 

  [ [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 44 ], 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 

  [ [29, 30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0], 53 ]
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  [ [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 5 ], 0,

  [ [31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 14 ], 0, 

  [ [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1], 22 ], 0, 

  [ [28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3], 31 ], 

  [ [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], 35 ], 0, 

  [ [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 44 ], 0, 

  [ [29, 30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0], 53 ]
]
```

Comment: Could `arr1[0]` equal zero?  If yes does that mean that `arr2[0][1]` equals zero?

Comment: Please clarify "but when condition become false the zero should only add one time instead of repeating". What condition?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the numbers are unique, you could use [`rassoc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Array.html#rassoc-method) to fetch the sub-array from `arr1`:

```
arr1.map { |i| arr2.rassoc(i) || i }
#=> [
#     [[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 5], 0,
#     [[31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 14], 0,
#     [[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1], 22], 0,
#     [[28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3], 31],
#     [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], 35], 0,
#     [[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 44], 0,
#     [[29, 30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0], 53]
#  ]
```

Comment: If `arr1` is not unique something like `arr1.flat_map { |i| (a = arr2.select {|_,e| e == i }).empty? ? i : a }` would work too.

Answer (score 3):

This is not very Ruby-like but it should be relatively efficient because it avoids the need to search arrays.

```
a1 = arr1.size.times.with_object([]) do |i,a|
  n = arr1[i]
  next if n.zero?
  a << (i < arr1.size-1 && arr1[i+1].zero?) 
end 
  #=> [true, true, true, false, true, true, false]
```

A zero should be inserted after `arr2[i]` if `a1[i]` is `true`.

```
arr2.each_with_object([]) do |a2,a|
  a << a2
  a << 0 if a1.shift
end 
  #=> [
  #    [[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 5], 0,
  #    [[31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 14], 0,
  #    [[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1], 22], 0,
  #    [[28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3], 31],
  #    [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], 35], 0,
  #    [[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2], 44], 0,
  #    [[29, 30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0], 53]
  #   ]
```

Comment: Minor assumption made with is that `arr1` does not start with 0

Comment: @engineersmnky, if `arr2[0][1]` equalled zero that presumably would mean that `arr2[0][1]` equalled zero, but if `arr2[i][1]` could equal zero for any `i`, `arr1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, for example, would not tell us where (here two) zeroes should be inserted.

Comment: I was referring to `arr1[0] == 0`. The way I read "when the condition becomes false" does not imply that it cannot begin in a false state and thus `result[0] == 0`; however in your methodology this will be skipped because `next if n = arr1[0] and n.zero?` For example: https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/TrueLongtermIntroductory#main.rb

Comment: I guess for clarity's sake I should have said does not start with a false condition (which is represented by 0 in this case)

Comment: @engineersmnky, I've asked for clarification.